# Assigning child class to a parent class typed property

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript

I do have the following 2 base clases:

```
class BaseModel {}

class BaseService{
  protected model:BaseModel;
}
```

Now I want to implement BaseHelper and BaseService for a specific use case and assign a derived class to my property.

```
class MyModel extends BaseModel{
  constructor(param:string){
    super();
  }
}

class MyService extends BaseService {
  model = MyModel;  
}
```

However, this gives me the error Type 'typeof MyModel' is not assignable to type 'BaseModel'.

**Important: I want to attach the class MyModel, not an instance of the class MyModel!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate `MyModel` using the `new` keyword (`new MyModel()`).
You assigned the actual class (`model = MyModel`) instead of an instance of it.

Also, you might want to make `BaseService` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
class BaseModel {}

class BaseService<T extends BaseModel> {
    protected model: T;

    constructor(model: T) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}

class MyModel extends BaseModel{}

class MyService extends BaseService<MyModel> {
    constructor() {
        super(new MyModel());
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseModel%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BaseService%3CT%20extends%20BaseModel%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20model%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(model%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.model%20%3D%20model%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyModel%20extends%20BaseModel%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyService%20extends%20BaseService%3CMyModel%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09super(new%20MyModel())%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

---

#### Edit

If you need the class and not the instance, then something like:

```
class BaseModel {}

type BaseModelConstructor = { new(): BaseModel };

class BaseService {
    protected modelCtor: BaseModelConstructor;
}

class MyModel extends BaseModel {}

class MyService extends BaseService {
    modelCtor = MyModel;  
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseModel%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20BaseModelConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%20new()%3A%20BaseModel%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BaseService%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20modelCtor%3A%20BaseModelConstructor%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyModel%20extends%20BaseModel%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyService%20extends%20BaseService%20%7B%0D%0A%09modelCtor%20%3D%20MyModel%3B%20%20%0D%0A%7D))

Or you can use generics here as well:

```
class BaseModel {}

type BaseModelConstructor<T extends BaseModel> = { new(): T };

class BaseService<T extends BaseModel> {
    protected modelCtor: T;
}

class MyModel extends BaseModel {}

class MyService extends BaseService<BaseModel> {
    modelCtor = MyModel;  
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseModel%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20BaseModelConstructor%3CT%20extends%20BaseModel%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BaseService%3CT%20extends%20BaseModel%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20modelCtor%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyModel%20extends%20BaseModel%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyService%20extends%20BaseService%3CBaseModel%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09modelCtor%20%3D%20MyModel%3B%20%20%0D%0A%7D))

---

If your derived classes have different ctor signatures then you can either deal with it in the base ctor type:

```
type BaseModelConstructor<T extends BaseModel> = { new(...args: any[]): T };
```

Here you can pass any count and kind of parameters, but you can also supply different signatures:

```
type BaseModelConstructor<T extends BaseModel> = { 
    new(): T;
    new(str: string): T;
    new(num: number, bool: boolean): T;
};
```

But you can also use a different type per derived class:

```
type MyModelConstructor = { new(param: string): MyModel };
```

Comment: I just updated my question: I want to assign a class, not a class instance

Comment: I still get the error: Class 'MyService' incorrectly extends base class 'BaseService'.
  Types of property 'model' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof MyModel' is not assignable to type 'new () => BaseModel'.

Comment: @schacki The code I provided does not produce errors (check out the links to playground) so that means that your implementation results in errors. Please update your question with the new code.

Comment: Ok, got the difference. I just updated my question. MyModel's constructor has additional parameters and therefore a different call signature. What is the most elegant way to have arbitrary additional params in the constructor?

Comment: @schacki It's hard to give an elegant solution for a general problem in this case, it depends on what you are actually doing (in oppose to your example here). I updated my answer with a few ways.

Answer (score 1):

`model` should be an instance of `MyModel`:

```
class MyModel extends BaseModel{}

class MyService extends BaseService {
  model = new MyModel()
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question: I want to assign a class, not a class instance

Answer (score 0):

Use instance of BaseModel

```
class MyService extends BaseService {
  model = new MyModel();  
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question: I want to assign a class, not a class instance