# Typescript - Method inheritance with return type

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

I would like to make a base class that contains methods that all childs will used. Howerver, I'm having trouble to inherit methods that return the class object.

Here is what I would like to achieve:

```
export class BaseModel {

    constructor(){}

    fromJson(model: BaseModel): BaseModel {
        if (!model) {
            return new BaseModel();
        }

        Object.keys(model)
            .map(key => this[key] = model[key]);

        return this;
    }
}

export class ChildModel extends BaseModel {
}

...
const child: ChildModel = new ChildModel().fromJson(someJson);
...
```

But I get compilation errors:

> Type 'BaseModel' is not assignable to type 'ChildModel'.

The only way I was able to achieve this is by defining the 'fromJson' method inside the MyChild class, like this:

```
fromJson(child: ChildModel): ChildModel {
    super.fromJson(child);
    return this;
}
```

But this is not what I want. If I go into the process of inheritance, it's because I would like generic methods to remove the code in every children.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540956/assigning-child-class-to-a-parent-class-typed-property), but I have some difficulties to understand and implement it into my scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `this` type which always refers to the type of the instance itself. However it requires you to cast `new BaseModel()` as `this`:

```js
export class BaseModel {

    constructor(){}

    fromJson(model: BaseModel): this {
        if (!model) {
            return new BaseModel() as this;
        }

        Object.keys(model)
            .map(key => this[key] = model[key]);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution, I like it